# Network switch in-between modem and two routers

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, modem

I live in an apartment and the provided modem only has one ethernet out port.

In order to wire ethernet to the rest of the apartment I put in a 5 port switch.

Will I able able to connect two routers to Ethernet throughout the apartment?

The reason I don't have the router with the modem is the compartment is too small to fit both devices and the closet space is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Lets start with why you want 2 routers. do you actually? you can do what you describe with three routers, in a pyramid, but that seems silly. Also you could try an enterprise grade router like a ubiquity ER8 (they're like 300USD) where there are multiple router ports, that you can dynamically assign, so you could have a single wan uplink to the modem, but have two router interfaces for your interior switches to connect to. same result but one device instead of 3.

Comment: I wanted one router for the office, and one for the media center. They are opposite ends of the apartment and the speed goes from 110Mbps to around 6Mbps between the two rooms. Something here hurts the Wi-Fi incredibly much. The cellphones seem to do just fine, but all other devices suffer.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: well thats a reason to have several switches (or APs if you want wireless), but not really several routers. I'd put in one router, and several switches/APs to get the signal where you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *could* work, but it depends on a lot of things.

- If the modem is already a router, then it should work just fine and you wouldn't even need extra routers.
- If the modem is just a modem, then it would work in theory, but there are two common problems which may occur, depending on what your ISP provides:

  1. Some ISPs only issue a single external IP address per customer port – any device connected to the modem will get the same DHCP lease. Using a switch would mean both routers would compete for the same address.
  2. Some WAN technologies (LTE, cable/docsis) do not support modems acting as true bridges – the modems themselves must acquire the IP address, so if they're not routers they have to be pseudo-bridges which cannot handle more than one device connected at a time.

I would try to find a way to connect a single router directly to the modem, maybe lut it somewhere outside and use a longer ethernet cable, or buy a very small router (possibly one that doesn't do wifi, *just* a router).

Comment: I was afraid of that... I believe you're right. Would something like [this](https://smile.amazon.com/TRENDnet-Broadband-Recognizing-Protection-TW100-S4W1CA/dp/B00006I5XC/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=wired%2Brouter&qid=1611179032&sr=8-5&th=1) work then? Other options I see are near $100 which is unfortunate. [This](https://smile.amazon.com/Ubiquiti-Networks-ER-X-Router/dp/B0144R449W/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=wired+router&qid=1611179032&sr=8-4) could be another option.

Comment: Yes, I would probably go with the ER-X because I like the flexibility.

Comment: Two routers did not work off of the modem, but the router in-between the modem and other routers worked. Thanks so much :)